# Is it a good experience if we use three modals in a row?

Tags: modal-windows, modal

I would like to be sure if it is a good experience for the user when, for example, you update your password and then the user selects the "Save changes" button; this action appears in the first modal asking the user where they would like to receive the authentication code, then the user selects the option (text message, phone call or email) and clicks the "next" button. The second modal appears with the field to add the authentication code, and here is the situation we want to solve: We are not sure if we want to show in this modal a checkbox option in which the system asks the user if they wish to register the device where the authentication code was sent, or system should show another modal only with checkbox option.

What do you suggest?

Comment: can you add a mockup? Your scenario isn't very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to open a modal (also known as a dialog) and incorporate some navigation logic into it.

Regarding dialog behavior, here are a couple of things to avoid: stacking multiple levels of dialogs on top of each other or closing and reopening the dialog with new content to transition to the next view.

You can open a dialog, and the content inside may change when you press a button that leads to a new view. So, while you treat the transitions you mentioned between views as navigation within the dialog content and don't close and open a new dialog, it should be perfectly usable and understandable. You may also need to consider giving the user the option to go back if the context requires it, just as you would in common navigation with pages.

Think of it as a mini page navigation within your dialog. It's "mini" because you shouldn't make it too complex. Even though you're navigating, it should be an extremely short and simple interaction since the dialog isn't the main navigation area.

Comment: Thank you!  This is very enriching to solve my design issue.